# Javascript: Can I write a data structure with JSON when there are references?

Tags: javascript, json, reference

If I have an object like this

```
var me = {};
me.structure = {};
me.structure.yea = 'hola';
me.sons = [];
me.sons[0] = {};
me.sons[0].yea = 'yo!';

var all = {};
all.pa1 = me;
all.pa1_365 = me;
all.pa1_file0 = me;
all.pa1_file1 = me;
all.pa1_365_file0 = me;
all.pa1_365_file1 = me;

console.log(JSON.stringify(all));
```

I can see that the JSON code destroys the reference structure. What is then the best way to store a structure like this?

- the option of restoring the references when JSON is again parsed doesn't work when you have many "me" variables, you'd have to loop too much
- the option of using another strategy to store the information (here I am using the keys of the object to have different ways to refer to the same structure) is obviously correct, but that would be a workaround of the problem - maybe this is the only solution

Comment: What do you mean with "the JSON code destroys the reference structure" ? That once you parse it back to an object you'll have multiple instances of the 'me' object?

Comment: References are never stored. It will always be parsed!

Comment: @Shilly yes, I mean that you lose the references and that you also store redundant information. But Bergi is completely right, this question is duplicated, I didn't choose wisely enough my keywords when I was searching for it